# Remove duplicates from StringBuilder

Tags: java, android, stringbuilder

I have a problem with `StringBuilder`. I want to remove all duplicate entry from it.

The important part of my code looks like the snipped below:

```
if (cb.isChecked() == false) {
    Pattern.compile(cb.getText().toString()).matcher(checkedcontacts)
        .replaceAll("");
    checkedcontacts.replace(
        checkedcontacts.indexOf(cb.getText().toString()), cb
                    .getText().toString().length(), "");
    }
```

Comment: You can use "Set" for removing duplicates

Comment: It's not easy to see where you are using a `StringBuilder` in your code example. Perhaps you can post a bit more code to demonstrate what you want to achieve?

Comment: not need to write `if (cb.isChecked() == false) {`
you can better do `if (!cb.isChecked()) {`

Answer (score 4):

Everything seems fine but you are not assigning your data to variable after replaceAll("") and replace() methods. Try it like this.

```
if (cb.isChecked() == false) {
    checkedcontacts = Pattern.compile(cb.getText().toString()).matcher(checkedcontacts).replaceAll("");
    checkedcontacts = checkedcontacts.replace(checkedcontacts.indexOf(cb.getText().toString()), cb.getText().toString().length(), "");
}
```